# How is validating a parameter "high up" on the callstack done?

Tags: c#, parameter-passing, callstack

I've been reading the Framework Design Guidelines book, a book on designing frameworks in .NET, with excerpts from the framework designers on the decisions they made regarding each section (E.g. parameter design, exception handling, etc).

One of the tips, under parameter design, is to validate parameters as "high up on the callstack" as possible. This is because the work here is not as expensive as it is low on the callstack, so a performance penalty is not as costly when validating high up in the callstack.

Does this mean that when I pass parameters into a method or constructor, I validate them before doing anything else, or do I do so just before using the parameters (So there could be 100 lines of code between the parameter in the definition and the usage of the parameter)?

Thanks

Comment: I believe your first conclusion is correct, validate it at the last possible case where the value could be changed in a way that it would adversely affect performance or cause a problem.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, that is validate first then execute code (Read up on Design-by-Contract pattern.) The benefits are pretty simple. Exceptions are expensive especially when they bubble up through layers. So validating parameters first and then executing code is a good practice.

Comment: Is this as soon as they're passed in or just before they're used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't read the specific guidelines you mention, but I expect they're talking about the case where method `A` calls method `B`, which calls method `C` and a parameter value gets passed through all three calls. It's better to validate that parameter at the start of method `A` than somewhere in the middle of method `C` because if it's invalid, then you get to skip all of the stuff that happens in `A` and `B` and the start of `C`. This is especially true if `B` or `C` are called inside loops because then the low-level validation would occur many times instead of just once at the start of `A`.

Of course you have to balance that with how complicated the validation of the parameter is. It may just be way easier to understand if you validate it in the same place you use it.

Answer (score 4):

1. Prefer to validate in the public API of an assembly. That means the public methods of the public classes.
2. Prefer to validate in the public methods of your classes. So if your class requires a non-null pointer to another object to work correctly, you could enforce this by requiring it as a constructor parameter and throwing an exception when a null pointer is supplied. From that point forward none of the member methods need to test if the pointer is non-null.

The idea is that no user can break your class (or assembly) by feeding invalid data. Of course the code won't work either way, but if you fail in a controlled way, it's more clear to the calling code what is wrong, and you won't have unpleasant side effects like resource leaks (or worse).

Comment: As a side note, if you are the author of both calling and called code, I think it is often enough to fail early (allow null ptr exceptions to get thrown etc.) rather than explicit validation. Either way one should fail or validate early.

Answer (score 2):

Failing fast is generally a good practice. All arguments passed to a method should be validated as soon as possible, without any unnecessary calculations being performed before, because that eases debugging and allows for easier recovery from the faulty situation.

In respect to input validation I consider performance a minor concern.

Answer (score 1):

Validate them as early as you can in your method!

Answer (score 1):

What I believe this to mean is that you should validate data that could be invalid as soon as you receive it. Once it has been validated then no more checks are needed. If you wait until the bottom of the call stack then you may have to validate many times because your call tree may have many branches.

I would whole-heartedly agree with this advice, but not on the grounds of performance. By validating at the point of entry you are in a much better position to give a meaningful error message to the client who supplied the data. And by reducing the amount of validation that you do, you will end up with much clearer code.